# How to use ajax to replace text in a box? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am making an application where each text box on a page has a "translate" button next to it. When the user clicks on this button, the text in the box would translate to english, via a function I would define in that page's controller. (If the text is already english, the button would not show up)

Where would I start going about how to do this? There are several rails/ajax tutorials on the web. Are there any that go about solving a use-case semi-similar to mine? I'm contacting the server for translating the text, so is this even an ajax request anymore?

Comment: you're using a form with `form_for` or `form_tag` ? , nvm, just explain the form structure you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm contacting the server for translating the text, so is this even an
>   ajax request anymore?

Yep.

[Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) is basically just a technology which allows Javascript to send requests on your behalf. It stands for `Asynchronous Javascript And XML` - basically meaning it can send data / requests "behind the scenes"

When you say your function needs to send a request to the server, you're going to be using `ajax` to do that, unless you want to reload the page.

--

**Button**

The way you'd handle the translation is as follows:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", ".translate", function(){

    var text = $(".text_element).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "pages/translate",
        data: {text: text},
        success: function(data){ }
    });
});
```

This will allow you to send the request you require to the server, of which you can then process the response.

--

**Controller**

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :controller do
    collection do
        get :translate
    end
end
```

To do this, you'll be best using the [`respond_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to) block in your controller:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, :json, only: :translate

   def translate
       respond_with ...
   end
end
```